# How does Java parse XDR information?

Tags: java-sdk, xdr

I need to get the transaction records. This information seems to be in XDR. How can I parse it in Java?

Answer (score 1):

To get the last transactions you can make a request to an Horizon server, if you don't have one you can use public horizon server (horizon.stellar.org) but its limited.

For query transactions you have to call **transactions** endpoint
[HERE AN EXAMPLE](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GB2PXXMCCNETER57LTHQLCTBPVRFLZVIHRANYLRTTYJX4AF6KPSEASDZ/transactions?%7Bcursor=now,limit=10,order=desc%7D) 
as you can see there are also human readble informations isn't necessary translating from XDR.

Here the infos that you can receive from transactions' endpoint

- **Transaction's ID/Hash**
- **Paging_token**
- **Ledger count**
- **created_at** (datetime of transaction)
- **source_account**
- **source_account_sequence** (sequence number of source account's transaction)
- **fee_paid** (in stroops)
- **operation_count**
- **memo_type**
- **memo** (content of memo field)

Answer (score 1):

I have just written a patch for the Java SDK to deserialize TransactionEnvelope XDR.

https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/pull/117

If you can wait, hopefully it will be approved and merged. After which you can simply call `Transaction.fromEnvelopeXdrBase64(base64String)`.

If you can't wait, you can copy the code in that PR directly to your project. Specifically, [this method](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/77d64ea6d58ebe8f330f2b2d53698ae7b1d48ed3/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/Transaction.java#L243-L256) and the methods it calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Transaction XDR encoded as a base64 string, you can use [`Transaction.fromEnvelopeXdr(string)`](https://stellar.github.io/java-stellar-sdk/org/stellar/sdk/Transaction.html#fromEnvelopeXdr-java.lang.String-) to get a `Transaction` object back.

Comment: Yes, this works as of 0.3.0 (released late 2018).

Answer (score 0):

The XDR classes in the sdk are generated using [xdrgen](https://github.com/stellar/xdrgen) from the xdr idl files in stellar core. So if you want to parse XDR either use the stubs in the sdk or generate them yourself using that.